# When purchasing software, how many releases of Ubuntu will that software be available to me?

Tags: software-center

As in the title, if I purchase software and install the next version of Ubuntu will I have to purchase it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It is linked to your Ubuntu One account.

This is apart from the fact that you don't have to reinstall Ubuntu when the next version is released: you just let Update Manager perform the upgrade for you!

Comment: But what if you do a clean install?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#commercial-reinstalling

Answer (score 3):

As Jonathon says: it's linked to your UbuntuOne account.

I don't know if you get newer versions though (in case that would be required for a newer Ubuntu version).

Comment: That is a good question, part of what I was wondering